# My bootstrap image keeps cutting into my paragraph in mobile

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am trying to get an image to pull-right and display block when in mobile, but my image keeps cutting into my text. Can anybody help me figure out how to make the image appear on top, then the text?

Here is the link: http://o-pd.com/AP

```
<div class="clearfix">
   <img src="http://o-pd.com/AP/img/John-Abraham.jpg" alt="John Abraham" class="pull-right img-responsive gap-left" width="200" height="200">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lacinia pharetra lacus, id pulvinar ligula molestie et. Duis in ultricies ipsum. Etiam tellus diam, eleifend in rutrum ac, facilisis quis dolor. Nulla ex elit, malesuada vel commodo ac, volutpat nec odio. Duis ac turpis dignissim, placerat lectus quis, venenatis dui.</p>
                  <br/><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lacinia pharetra lacus, id pulvinar ligula molestie et. Duis in ultricies ipsum. Etiam tellus diam, eleifend in rutrum ac, facilisis quis dolor. Nulla ex elit, malesuada vel commodo ac, volutpat nec odio. Duis ac turpis dignissim, placerat lectus quis, venenatis dui.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Image should be at the right of the text on big screen, and at the top of the text on mobiles?

Comment: That is correct @Mistalis

Answer (score 0):

[image: after applying this changes the image will appear as you are see]

```css
/*we will use media query to change the direction of img*/
@media (max-width:500px){
  .pull-right{
    float:left !important;
    }
  p{
    clear:both;
  
  }
  }
```

Comment: I added the code to the bootstap min (very bottom), and I've tried other places but it won't kick in. Should I be adding it somewhere specifically @Eng_Farghly?

Comment: @Noy oh,you must add this code in the end of  your css file

Comment: my dear you shouldn't add this code to bootstrap file , this code must be add to css file only . if you found problem again , you should upload your files and I will solve  any problem to you

Comment: I added the css at the end of grayscale.min.css. It works when I try it in firebug though..

Comment: Here is the link @eng_farghly abrahampsychiatry.com - I added the style at the end of my css...

Comment: I am sorry @Noy in the first answer I forget (px) you can view  answer after  editing

Comment: @Noy    you can download your website from this link   http://www.mediafire.com/download/5k0iqf30r3xao1a/website+Noy.rar        , l add changes to your website to  work correctly